# NHibernate 'Write Only' collection, if there is such a thing?

Tags: nhibernate, collections, nhibernate-mapping

Does anyone know if it's possible to add an item to a collection without actually retrieving the persisted items in that collection? Is there a mapping that will allow me to achieve this?

I have a scenario where I'm performing some batch processing on some customer objects. I want to add some notes to my customers as I go but don't want/need the already persisted notes for that customer as it's a background process and simply adds to the collection.

Answer (score 2):

[18.5.3. Bags and lists are the most efficient inverse collections](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-collections-mostefficentinverse)

In any case, you can skip the collection completely and just use a many-to-one (i.e. set `Note.Customer` instead of adding a Note to `Customer.Notes`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your original question, but I can offer a workaround- create a new Note object, set its Customer property to the wanted customer, and persist it. simple, and works well for me.

Comment: I've been toying with that idea but at the moment I don't have/need a presister for my Note class and was hoping to keep it that way.

Comment: @Matt: nice thing about nHib is all you need to do is 'Session.Save(obj);' and that's all. the Session object is your persister, and you already have it :). If you're using repositories and want to abstract your Session, you can write a generic 'Save<T>' method in your repository base class. that's what I did.

Comment: I do have my Session abstracted and kept in an NHibernate wrapper library, and a generic implementation of all the CRUD methods. For now I'm using this method. If you mark the collection as inverse=true, the collection isn't loaded when I call my AddNote method, BUT when I save, I don't get an insert into my link table. Close but not quite there...

Comment: so I think you *can* use the solution i offered: you won't need a presister for your Note class; just use the generic implementation of the CRUD methods you already have.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into HQL update/inserts, because if you want to work with entities in a collection without loading the collection nor have a belongs-to relationship on the collection items, that is what might be available.